# How to get an image to fit inside the viewport?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I know there are SO many variations of this question but I can't find an answer that works. The problem is simple. I'm making a landing page and I need a `<div>` that fills the entire viewport. I then need an image and navbar to both fit into that `<div>`. However, when I try this the image always ends up expanding past the viewport. I am clueless as how to fix this. I've tried everything I can think of.

Here is a [js fiddle for it](https://jsfiddle.net/evqypcam/3/)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar">
    <p>About</p>
    <p>Features</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/01/25/08/55/apple-iphone-12-pro-max-5947688_1280.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.navbar {
  display: flex
}

.navbar > p {
  padding: 3px;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: red;
}

.col {
  width: 50%;
}


html {
 height: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: you can use flex inside flex, then set size of image to zero but min-size to 100% + object-fit  see the picture : https://jsfiddle.net/63gdbpxm/

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS and it will be fixed. You forgot to limit the width of `img`

```
.col img {
  width: 100%
}
```

Comment: The image still extends past the boundary vertically...

Comment: you can use overflow-y: "hidden" on parent element. But in that case parent element should have a definite height